# CommandButton - Erro ao chamar método

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, dialog

Sou iniciante com `JSF`, desenvolvimento web, e estou com um problema ao usar o componente `Dialog`, do `PrimeFaces`, dentro de um `DataTable`.

A idéia era a seguinte: Temos um lista de presentes para um chá de panela, o convidado da festa escolhe o presente que quer dar, e clica no botão `Escolher`, dai abre um `Dialog` Contendo um `OuputLabel` e um `InputText` contendo o nome do convidado, e um botão para confirmar que irá salvar o presente escolhido, o nome e o telefone da pessoa.

Fiz um código teste sem banco de dados, apenas um protótipo do que será, entretanto está apresentando inconsistência, conforme imagem, **e o `commandButton`, não está chamando o método `teste` do `ManagedBean`**:

[image: Depois de inserir o nome e confirmar aparece isto!]

--- Managed Bean ---

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ConfirmarPresenteBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String nome;
    private String telefone;

    public void teste() {
        System.out.println("Nome: " + this.nome);
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }
}
```

--- XHTML ---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title><ui:insert name="titulo">Chacolate de Panela</ui:insert></title>
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="sistema.css" />
</h:head>

<h:body>

<script>
  function tratarConfirmacaoPresente(args) {
    if (!args.validationFailed) {
      confirmarPresenteDialog.hide();
    }
  }
</script>

<div id="container">
    <h:form id="dataTable">
      <p:dataTable value="#{listaPresentesBean.presentes}" var="presente"
        sortBy="#{presente.nomePresente}" rows="10" paginator="true"
      paginatorPosition="bottom" rowsPerPageTemplate="10, 15, 20">

        <p:column headerText="Lista de Presentes">
          <h:outputText value="#{presente.nomePresente}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="" width="20">
          <p:commandButton value="Escolher" id="botaoEscollher"
          onclick="confirmarPresenteDialog.show(); return false;" />

          <!-- Dialog -->
          <p:dialog header="Confirmar Presente"
            widgetVar="confirmarPresenteDialog" modal="true"
            resizable="false">

            <h:panelGroup id="confirmacaoPanel">
              <p:messages />

              <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome" />
                <p:inputText id="nome" required="true"
                  value="#{confirmarPresenteBean.nome}" />
              </h:panelGrid>

              <p:commandButton value="Confirmar"
                update="confirmacaoPanel"
                action="#{confirmarPresenteBean.teste}" />

            </h:panelGroup>
          </p:dialog>
        </p:column>

      </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</div>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, Tom! Veja algumas dicas de como formatar seus posts [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) e [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) e, se tiver um minuto, faça o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)!

Comment: Tente isolar o seu componente dialog em um outro form.

Comment: Não cheguei a implementar seu codigo para testar, mas pelo q obsevei acredito que o metodo (.teste) deve ser implementado no botão que vai chamar a ação de compor o Modal. Por acaso sua necessidade não eh quando clicar no Botão Escolher ele abrir o Modal e popular com a resposta de "System.out.println("Nome: " + this.nome);"?

Comment: Tira o dialog de dentro da table

Comment: @AnselmoPfeifer Na verdade eu o criei o método (.teste) apenas para testar se o botão estava funcionando. O problema era com o (h:form) mesmo. Retirei do DataTable e deixei o (h:form) apenas dentro do Dialog e resolveu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tire o `dialog` de dentro da Tabela em seguida altere o botão que esta dentro do `dialog` de `action` para `actionListener`.

[Aqui](http://blog.triadworks.com.br/quando-usar-action-ou-actionlistener-com-jsf) tem um artigo onde as diferenças entre action e actionListener são explicadas.

Comment: Valeu pelo retorno kra, vou estudar sobre isto. Entretanto quando isolei o Dialog dentro de um h:form, mesmo dentro da tabela, resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Que bom, mas cuidado, creio que não seja uma boa prática. Você pode problema futuramente.

Comment: Tom, Se seu problema foi resolvido então classifique a resposta como resolvida (é uma 'setinha certo' verde).